# Delete object from AWS S3 bucket (not in code)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just want to update my index.html file in an S3 bucket. I was going to delete the file and then add the new one just using the website. I can't see any way to do this. Am I thinking wrong? Am I supposed to do all this stuff in code? I just want to hack it together for now so can I do it on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go into S3 select a single file and delete it. Afterwards you can upload a new file.

Old console: Select the file in S3 and click `Actions` and then click `delete`.
New console: Select the file in S3 and click `More` and than click `delete`.

You could use a client like [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the console, you can select your file, click "More" and delete is one of the options. There's the upload button to the left as well.  I also suggest getting familiar with the AWS CLI so that you also can sync directories and such.